# How to create a protocol conform Comparable in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have a use case to compare the enployee's rank. Here is what I want to do:

```
protocol Enployee: Comparable {
    var id: String { get }
    var rank: Int { get }
    var name: String { get }
    var type: String { get }
}

extension Enployee {
    static func <(lhs: Enployee, rhs: Enployee) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rank < rhs.rank
    }
}
```

But I got the following error:

> Protocol 'Enployee' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Then I changed my code:

```
extension Enployee {
    static func <(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rank < rhs.rank
    }
}
```

I can compile it. But when I continue working on my user case:

```
struct Engineer: Enployee {
    var id: String
    var rank: Int
    var name: String
    let type: String = "Engineer"
}

struct Manager: Enployee {
    var id: String
    var rank: Int
    var name: String
    let type: String = "Manager"
}

let staff1 = Engineer(id: "123", rank: 2, name: "Joe")
let staff2 = Engineer(id: "124", rank: 2, name: "Frank")
let staff3 = Manager(id: "101", rank: 10, name: "John")

public struct Department<T: Comparable> {
}

let queue = Department<Enployee>()
```

I got another error message:

> Protocol 'Enployee' as a type cannot conform to 'Comparable'

Any idea?

Comment: "Employee" is how to spell that word. ('m', not 'n')

Comment: @Jessy Typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what the problem is. Having declared `Department<T: Comparable>` you cannot resolve T as Enployee; it is a protocol, not a type conforming to Comparable (such as Engineer).

A generic has to be resolved to *one* type. It would be legal to declare `Department<T: Enployee>` if that is what you really mean. But then you are setting yourself up for multiple Department types, a department of Manager and a department of Engineer. That is probably not what you want, so this is a bad use of a generic.

Moreover, type strings are a horrifically bad smell:

```
struct Engineer: Enployee {
    var id: String
    var rank: Int
    var name: String
    let type: String = "Engineer" // uck
}
```

It seems much more likely that you want a class and subclasses here. Why fight against OOP?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I can implement it in class without problem. But I want to implement it in more protocol oriented way. This is what I really mean. There are different `Employee` (sorry for the typo in my original post) such as `Manager` and `Engineer`. But I want to compare their ranks.

Comment: You can compare their ranks without making them Comparable.

Comment: I know how to compare with `Comparable` but I have a existing `Queue` class which need a `Comparable` as a generic type.